# After successful migration from Magento 1 to Magento 2 with data migration tool, I don't see Cron Scheduler Option in the Admin

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, data-migration-tool

After successful migration from Magento 1 to Magento 2.3.4, I don't see Cron Scheduler Option in the Admin. Please advise me as to how to bring it in.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cron Scheduler Option not showing any personal tab but cron scheduler showing the follow path : -

1. On the Admin sidebar, go to `Stores > Settings > Configuration`.
2. In the left panel, expand `Advanced` and choose `System`.
3. Expand Expansion selector the `Cron` section.

And more information refer this link :-

**https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/system/cron.html**

Comment: Thanks a lot Mohit. I found this at the place your answer specified. It would have been if it was visible when you just click on Stores in the Admin